# failed to connect to mongoose lab

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Ive create mongoose lab DB and Im getting error in the command line that it failed to connect(i've provided the right user and pass),what am I doing wrong and how can I overcome this issue?

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://myuser:123456@ds063200.mongolab.com:61200/flights',function(err){
    if(err) throw err;
})
```

im using node.js

Comment: maybe just try again in a few minutes / hours. mongolab mention that they don't guarantee 100% uptime for their free databases / accounts.

Comment: @northkildonan-there is a way to ping to it from diffrent app to test the connection ?maybe in the browser or some tool just to see if the connection is OK...

Comment: For a local connection you will need to install mongodb on your machine (small hint: install 64-bit version. it support journalling by default)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are using your MongoLab's `username` & `password` for connecting to your database.

You should define a username & password for your database in MongoLab control panel

for example I have a database named `'test'`, after login to Mongolab I'll go to https://mongolab.com/databases/test#users and add new username and password for `'test'` database

**`username: hamid, password:zzzz`**.

the connection for `test database` my mongolab will be

```
mongodb://hamid:zzzz@ds053438.mongolab.com:53438/test
```

[image]

**Updated: Test your connection via robomongo**

Connect to `mongolab`  via `robomongo`

Step 1: create new connection

[image]

Step 2: enter your address `ds063200.mongolab.com` and `61200` as your port

[image]

Step 3: enter `flights` as your database and your database user and password ('not mongolab user and password)

[image]

Comment: Thanks but I already do that,there is a way to test the connection in different way?not from node.js app ?maybe a way to ping to it from some tool or browser?

Comment: have you tried: `c:\mongo\bin\mongo ds063200.mongolab.com:61200/flights -u <dbuser> -p <dbpassword>`?

Comment: You have to run this code in Command window (windows key+R) + input cmd and enter then put the code.

Comment: Thanks but I dont have this path in the file system...Try to find mongo/bin without sucess...

Comment: 'c:\mongo\bin\mongo' is the location of your mongo that has been  installed. where did you install the mongo?

Comment: I've not install it I just use the monogo lab connection string

Comment: you can download it and install it for your test. or download http://robomongo.org/download.html and connect via that tool.

Comment: Thanks,if I download it I can use it locally instead of mongoo lab?if yes,which connection string should I use and which api to call it?1+ for your support...

Comment: Thanks a lot! I did your step and I didnt able to connect,I got error unable to connect,any idea why I put the exact user and pass...,maybe firewall or something....?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66014/discussion-between-disposer-and-mark).

Answer (score 0):

it's just a guess since i never used mongoose so far -  but i can't seem to find a connection string with a callback in the mongoose docs:
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/connection-string/

so maybe the connection function doesn't support a callback and you are just fine with this:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://myuser:123456@ds063200.mongolab.com:61200/flights');
```